# Any idea how to draw this Feynman diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-feynman

I have the following diagram from an article. Any idea how to reproduce this complicated diagram using latex? [image]

Comment: Do you mean “diagram” instead of “integral”?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if this is a Feynman integral.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={a=1.2;b=1.5;}]
 \draw[teal,dashed,rotate=-22.5] (90:a) foreach \X in {45,0,...,-180}
 {-- (\X:a) edge ++ (\X:0.5)} -- (135:a);
 \draw node[circle,fill,draw,inner sep=0.8ex](O){} 
   foreach \X [count=\Y] in {45,0,...,-225}
  {(\X:b) node[circle,draw,thin,inner sep=0.5ex](p\Y){} edge[very thick] (O)};
 \path foreach \X [count=\Y from 2] in {n-1,n,1,2,3} 
 {(p\Y) to[edge label={$a_{\X}$}] (O)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For subscripts I would put a \scriptscriptstyle because a_{n-1} is very close to the dotted line.:-) +1

Comment: Thanks, any idea how to put the three dots in the original diagram?

Comment: @SumitBanik Add e.g  `\path (0,1) node{$\dots$};`.